# What's a term for a question where the options are Response/No Response instead of Yes/No?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, questions

Is there a specific term for a question, such as ***Are you asleep**?* and ***Can you hear me**?*, where the binary is Response/No Response rather than Yes/No?

I feel like there are other aspects of this concept that orbit this specific question, so any related discussion at all is appreciated.

Comment: What domain are we in? We could call it a loaded question.

Comment: They don't have to be sarcastic, but they certainly could be used that way.

Comment: It’s not entirely true that the only options are response/no response. If I am wearing headphones, I might respond “I can’t hear you” to anything a person tries to say to me, and if what they said was “Can you hear me?”, then that response constitutes an honest “no”.

Comment: *1884   Bradley's Aids to Latin Prose §150   Questions that do not require an answer, but are only put in the form of a question in order to produce a greater effect,..are called rhetorical questions.* How far you wish to interpret “produce a greater effect” will be the criterion for using “rhetorical”.

Comment: Why are you assuming that in binary, 'Response/No Response' is different to 'Yes/No'? Can you say how you might design a system to include such a non-equivalence?

Answer (score 2):

They fall under the category of "yes-no questions" or ["closed-ended questions"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-ended_question). But note that no response to ***Are you asleep**?* means ***Yes***, whereas no response to ***Can you hear me**?* means ***No*** (the "default" response isn't the same for all such questions).

But I would also add that *these particular questions* aren't really "questions" at all, because to qualify as a question in the first place, the text must be written / spoken *and* read / heard<sup>1</sup>. So they're perhaps better described as "diagnostic tests".

---

("Discussion")

<sup>1</sup> Riffing off the well-known Zen koan *If a tree falls in a forest and no one is around to hear it, does it make a sound?*, perhaps we could call them "koan questions". But perhaps not, since the falling tree example ***is*** a "koan question" itself (assuming one person poses it to another, as opposed to a lone person mediating on the "question", but with no intention of *answering* it).

Or "quantum questions", given that in the strange world of quantum physics, the mere act of asking a question sometimes seems to affect the "answer", even though by standard (Newtonian) logic, the "theoretical" answer to the question *Did a photon pass by here?* should be the same whether explicitly asked or not (it's just that *we don't know* that answer until we ask).

Comment: The lack of a response to the question "Are you asleep?" does not amount to a "Yes."  The object of the question might be awake but refusing to answer.  Or the question might be asked through a closed door and the object of the question listening to rock music on a headset.

Comment: Tell that to the OP

Comment: They are definitely a sort of diagnostic test, but i believe they still qualify as questions. "Are you still ignoring me?" To ones face is most definitely heard, but only acknowledged if the answer is, or implied, 'No'(no matter the actual wording).

Comment: But the purpose of the question is, in essence, to find out enough information to know how to proceed. The actual truth of the matter(not asleep just not able to hear or read the question, etc) may not even be relevant, but the asker needed to know if further conversation is likely or whatever

Comment: I thought I was being helpful by editing the question to include another example where (no response) meant "No" instead of "Yes", but apparently not.

Comment: No no, it was definitely helpful! I apologize for implying otherwise

Comment: Oh, well put it back if you want. I can't say I hold out much hope for a better response here, though.

Comment: Whether or not it 100% applies in this scenario, I am very interested in the quantum question concept. It is going to be hanging out in my brain for a while. Thank you for that

Comment: @callinacrab I am pretty sure FumbleFingers's *quantum questions*  was a figure of speech referring to *quantum measurement.* The best as-little-technical-as-possible introduction to the subject I am aware of is [*Quantum Mechanics and Experience*](https://archive.org/details/quantummechanics00albe) by David Z. Albert. On YouTube, try [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GdqC2bVLesQ), but be aware that this is not a substitute for the book. For a weird offshoot into 'human' sciences (featuring literally *quantum questions*), see [this](https://www.pnas.org/doi/10.1073/pnas.1407756111).

Answer (score 0):

In general, within the domains where terminology is warranted —more specifically in philosophy—, questions like "Are you asleep?", "Can you hear me"?, "Are you there?" etc. can be called a **paradoxical question** as they contain a paradox, a self-contradictory or logically unacceptable question. For example, it doesn't make sense to ask "Are you asleep?" to someone asleep as they can't answer; plus, a hypothetical answer like "Yes, I am asleep" is a paradox also. Of course, there could be gray areas — for instance, they might be having a nap with closed eyes and they can hear you, or you could wake them up with your voice, or the question can be jocular in nature but generally these questions can be considered a paradox.

*[Dictionary of paradox (by Erickson, Glenn W., 1951-)](https://archive.org/details/dictionaryofpara0000eric/page/156/mode/2up)* explains paradoxical questions in detail as below and also adds a resolution to avoid a paradox:

> **Formulation.** Pairs of paradoxical questions and answers include the following:
>
> "Are you there?"                     "No, I am not here." 
>       "Are you asleep?"                   "Yes, I am asleep."
>       "Are you alive?"                       "No, I am dead."
>       "Are you mute?"                      "Yes, I am mute."
>       "Are you deaf?"                      "Yes, I am deaf."
>       "Can you hear me?"                "No, I cannot hear you."
>       "Do you speak English?"       "No, I do not speak any English."
>
> Paradoxical imperatives are of this sort:
>
> A sign that reads: “Ignore this sign.” 
>       A note that says only: “Do not read this note.” “Don’t listen to this utterance.” 
>       “Don’t listen to this utterance.” 
>       A posted bill that reads: “Post no bills.”
>
> **Explanation.** In the first case, the questions seem to ask for either a negative or an affirmative answer, but in fact only one of these answers would make sense, because one cannot consistently answer the question in the standard manner if one is not there, asleep, dead, deaf, dumb, cannot hear, or not an anglophone. Answering in the paradoxical manner is often a witty, snappy or sarcastic manner of saying the opposite. Unlike the questions, which can elicit useful information, the first three examples of imperatives not only have the scent of paradox but tend to be pragmatically useless, unless they are meant as some kind of joke. The last example of an imperative paradox does function to inform people of a policy of not posting bills in a certain place, but it does so by violating the policy in question, and might strike people as a somewhat absurd manner of implementing the policy in question. 
> **Resolution.** We sometimes avoid paradoxical responses by restating the questions in such a form that only one response is expected: “Tell me if you are there,” or “Raise you hand if you can hear me.” Sometimes we use a special form of diction that assumes the person cannot understand if he were to hear the more conventional form of the question: “Do you savvy my lingo?” Such measures do not guarantee success, however: does the other really not hear our statement, or does he just not raise his hand out of a perverse refusal to comply with our request?

**Pragmatic paradox liable question** is a more specific term given by Roy A. Sorensen, a professor at University of Texas at Austin, Department of Philosophy. Further reading here: Sorensen, Roy A. “Pragmatic Paradox Liable Questions.”
*Philosophical Studies: An International Journal for Philosophy in the Analytic Tradition*, vol. 39, no. 2, 1981, pp. 155–62. JSTOR, http://www.jstor.org/stable/4319446. Accessed 27 June 2023.

Comment: In general, they're **not** 'called ...  paradoxical question[s]'. I've not found one example on the internet where the string seems to be used as a regular term rather than adjective + noun.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth One can think as "In general, when they are categorized". There is the terminology tag and the topic can be evaluated within certain domains, more specifically philosophy. The question is not about colloquial usage. I've edited the statement to make it more clear.

Comment: ELU is always about common usages. D-I-Y suggestions are writing advice.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth IMO, some questions warrant uncommon or rare words/terms, more specifically terminology questions; and sometimes people specifically ask for it. Terms are often uncommon in nature. Of course, some terms can be more common as they might have been used or evaluated more often within publications or it might have gained usage in common parlance also; but some questions are much more specific and some terms can be uncommon. This question is more of a terminology question within philosophy. "ELU is always about common usages" can be discussed further in Meta if preferred.

Comment: Additionally, some terms are more descriptive in nature, rather than a completely novel coinage. The term "paradoxical question" is more of an extension of the common term "paradox" as the questions has paradoxical elements. The term is used in philosophical domain and I've provided a source; plus there is even a more specific term "pragmatic paradox liable question" used by an expert who evaluated the subject in philosophy.